# How to stop event propagation to other elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have written this function that binds to a button, which when clicked toggles the class to provide a dropdown. The only problem is is that I have multiple buttons on the same page that have the same functionality, and they all fire when one is clicked:

```
app.bind.DirectionDropdown = function(){
    $('.direction-button').bind('click', function(){
        $('.direction-dropdown').toggleClass('active');
    });
    
};
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="contact-card">

      <div class="contact-directions">
        <ul class="contact-directions-items">
          <li class="map-pin contact-directions-item"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span></a></li>
          <li class="contact-directions-item"><p>3700-1 Place Ville Marie</p></li>
          <li class="contact-directions-item"><p>Montreal, Quebec</p></li>
          <li class="contact-directions-item"><p>H3B 3P4 Canada</p></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" title="#" class="link-button direction-button animate-after">Directions</a>
      </div><!-- end .contact-directions -->

    </div><!-- end .contact-card -->

    <div class="direction-dropdown fade-in">
    
      <h4>Direction on how to get here...</h4>

      <a href="#" class="link-button direction-button">Close</a>

        <!-- content --> 

    </div><!-- end .direction-dropdown -->
```

How can I edit this function to fire only on the one button clicked, and not the others?

Comment: Give the button an id and bind the event to that id.

Comment: Pass your HTML markup so that we can help you better

Answer (score 2):

The event is not propagated to the other buttons, but inside the click event you select all buttons again. Use `this` to only select the button that was clicked.

```
app.bind.DirectionDropdown = function(){
    $('.direction-button').bind('click', function(){
        $('.direction-dropdown').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
};
```

Or, if you want to be able to close the menu by clicking the same button again:

```
app.bind.DirectionDropdown = function(){
    $('.direction-button').bind('click', function(){
        // Remove the class from all others, excluding the clicked one.
        $('.direction-dropdown').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('active');
        // Toggle for the clicked one.
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. What you say makes sense but it is still not working. The class still changes but with no event?

Comment: It is important to update the question with HTML markup. Notice that what gets '.active' is a '.direction-dropdown' (not '.direction-button')

Comment: Sorry, the class is added successfully to the one button only, but for some reason the dropdown doesn't fire? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a new, different problem, but there is not enough information to answer that. Maybe you can just leave this question (maybe accept, if the class is now added as you expected), and ask a new question with the new situation in it. That is, the script that now adds the correct class, and the HTML and CSS that go with it.

Comment: OK, so the problem is is that it your script adds the 'active' class to the .direction-button, and not the .direction-dropdown. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see you added the HTML. The solution: use [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/). I've modified the answer.